# Loading Lots Of Images From Server In Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

**Edit 2:** Even after the bounty, no one could give a full solution. So I solved it myself. I have posted my solution below.

I searched about it on Google and also found various good results. But since I'm not expert in server and backend kind of terms, I would like to ask it in a separate question. I have a website hosting which helps me run an institution's website.

1. In my android app, there should be an option such as "Photo Gallery" which shows images from my website (where I upload images in a folder). I think it can be done by managing some JSON files.
2. Let there be a folder \public_html\MyApp\Images which consists of folders like "Event1", "Event2", and so on. I upload images to these different folders and my Android app should load them (maybe separately giving users a choice to pick a folder).

Is it possible? If any advanced database system is required, please give me some intro links for that. Is there any way a JSON is automatically generated containing the links to images?

**Edit:** I had recently bought website hosting for backend kind of things and I haven't done any server-side scripting or anything. That's why a detailed answer is required. I don't know how to manage those images, simply upload images and put links in JSON or use some MySQL, SQL or whatever terms which I've never used.

Comment: manually add links to db or upload image and generate links

Comment: Don't put the upload folder in a public area, instead get your app to call a page which takes an argument, checks if the file exists, and if it does, servers it up, and if not, 404's

Comment: That's some problem I think. I'm new to server kind of things. Any help links will be appreciated. Edit: You mean PHP kind of files? Is that better approach or how it's better than the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. It's pretty easy to understand and implement and requires the knowledge of JSON only. Firstly, see this image from a directory of my website:

[image]

"event1", "event2" folders are the album names. We can create as many needed.

"**getfolders** file is very important. Content:

```
{
   "test":[
      {
         "sub":"event1",
         "content":"https://i1.wp.com/www.downloadinformer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/AMPFB.jpg?w=1366",
         "param":"1.php"
      },
      {
         "sub":"event2",
         "content":"myimageurl",
         "param":"myphpfilenamewithextension"
      }
   ]
}
```

We store album names here as you can see in "sub" field. "content" field contains the link to the thumbnail of the album and "param" contains the name of the corresponding PHP file. Don't worry, you don't need to learn PHP. It's a readymade script.

*1.php*

```
<?php

$indir = array_filter(scandir('event1'), function($item) {
        return $item[0] !== '.';
});

echo json_encode($indir);
?>
```

**What this PHP file does?** It lists all the names of files present in a specified folder. As you can see, we've specified "**event1**" as the folder name in this PHP file. So it will return all the images' names in a JSON format. Don't forget to specify this PHP file in "getfolders" file's "param" field.

Ok fine. So this was a sort of algorithm. If you have some confusion, please re-read it again. Now I will show some code.

I made two activities (Didn't prefer Fragments). One to show albums and second to show the images present in it.

**Activity 1->** Parses **getfolders** file and retrieves albums we specified earlier.

Album Title: **sub** field of the above JSON
, Album Thumbnail: **content** field of the above JSON
, (Hidden From User) Images Names List: **param** field

Thus we can show it in a Recyclerview with this information. Now we specify OnClickListener for its items.

**On Click Of An Item->** Start second activity using Intent and pass on the album name which is essentially the Folder name on our server. Thus we get access to the folder which contains images. Also pass the "param" field value. This gives us a url "www.mywebsite.com/..../alreadyspecifieddirectory/1.php"

**Activity->2** Implement a GridLayoutManager to show pictures to the user. Retrieve the earlier passed values using `getIntent()`. First we need to execute this PHP file and parse the JSON content. Here's some code:

```
 private void loadJSON(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            for (int i=2; i<jsonObject.length()+2;i++){
                                String value =jsonObject.getString(String.valueOf(i));
                                if (value.length()!=0) {
                                    ListItem item = new ListItem(value, mParam1+"/"+value, "nothing");
                                    listItems.add(item);
                                }
                            }
                            adapter = new PhotoLibraryAdapter(Photos.this,listItems,photosList,true);
                            photosList.setAdapter(adapter);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } catch (Exception e) {progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Please note that we started for loop from 2 because PHP file returns values from index 2 because value 0 and value 1 are waste values and named "." and ".." respectively.

Hence we get the names of images which we can pass on with url as:
"www.mywebsite.com/.../albumnameretrievedearlier/imagenamegivenbyPHPfile"

and pass it on to the adapter so that we can load the images using Picasso library.

That's it! If you have any question, feel free to ask in comments.

**EDIT 1:** Here's how it looks:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By the looks of it, you need 2 new database tables. One to store your albums, the other to store the individual images.

```
CREATE TABLE `album` (
   `album_id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `album_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `album_date` DATE NOT NULL);
```

`album` would store all the album metadata so it would store Event1 with its details, Event2 and so on..

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
   `image_id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `album_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   `image_date` DATE NOT NULL,
   `image_path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(album_id));
```

`images` would store all the images with their paths and the albums which they belong to using the `album_id` as the foreign key

Your queries for all images would be

```
SELECT * FROM `images`;
```

Images from a particular album would be queried like

```
SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `album_id` = *YOUR_ID*;
```

The output from the SQL query can be JSON encoded using

```
json_encode($query_result); //PHP code
```

**EDIT**: 
[Gallery App Example On Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)

It seems like you're saving images as BLOB directly into the database hence it's giving you the 64kb limit. It is better if you save paths of the images.
If that is not possible then base64 encode the images and store them in a column of type VARCHAR.

Comment: Any instructions on how to implement it, where? I assume you didn't see my Edit in post.

Comment: Does your host have cpanel? Use cpanel to get to phpmyadmin and create a database with tables there.

Comment: Yes but there's a limit of one database only and I can't seem to edit it

Comment: Yes you need only one database. You have to add the tables in that database.

Comment: Ok fine. I'm able to upload images but it limits it to 64 KB. Any idea to increase this limit? Then after it, how to proceed in the app. Please edit your answer for full instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You may get path of all images from server in JSON and display images by passing path with the help of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library as -

```
Picasso.with(context).load("imagepath").placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
```

.error(R.drawable.placeholder_error).into(imageView);

Answer (score 2):

**This solution does not need database.**

You need two API endpoints in PHP

Upload images /api/upload

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

2. List images

First list all directories under the upload directory:

```
$array = glob("uploads/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
echo json_encode($array);
```

3. If you want a specific folder, you can do so by sending the folder name and append to request URL and list all files.

   $array = glob("uploads/".$_REQUEST['dir']."/*");
   echo json_encode($array);

EDIT

```
// provides the current working directory
echo getcwd() ."\r\n";
// then navigate to path
// glob(getcwd() . DIRECTORY_OF_IMAGES));
// GLOB_BRACE tells to find all extensions in the brace
$array = glob(getcwd() . "/web/bundles/img/*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Read this article http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Upload these files in a folder and call them from app?

Comment: Yes. You can create a php file like upload.php and list.php (2nd section), if you dont want to use a framework (MVC) code.

Comment: @ParasSidhu, how you want to upload the file? using android Java code or HTML?

Comment: I can directly upload via FTP. That's the most efficient method for me... So in what form will these files return data. Sorry I am quite new and desperately want this feature implemented

Comment: Via FTP from FileZilla like client

Comment: They will be in json form.

Comment: @ParasSidhu, did you happen to get your problem resolved?

Comment: @ParasSidhu Cool

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english, You can add folder name in database when creating folder and load all folder name in app and also save images name in database with folder name table primery key as foreign key and when user select folder name use that folder name primery key and get all images with that key and load it in app.

Comment: Any links or tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bad english...

This images are saved as Blob type on your database or you save some kind of link to it?

You can send some kind of HTTP request with the folder name and then build a json with the images data. I use the Volley lib for HTTP requests in my app, very easy and work well

Comment: Yes I use Volley also but how to generate JSON and what is that blob type?

Comment: What do you use on your server side? PHP? RUBY? Blob is a database type of data that you can use to store images

Comment: I'm not using anything right now. New to these terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can really do this, it's possible and also practical, since you have a server. The first thing to do is to make an *API* with this api you can make URLs that android can fetch the JSON data from as objects, this means also you have to convert the images path to JSON. This great tutorial explains all about the process and even more. Since you're loading large number I suggest you use Picasso for the image caching and also recycler view

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-programming-tutorial-to-get-all-images-from-server/

Happy coding!

Comment: Problem is my server only allows 1 MySQL database and in that I can't seem to add images.

Answer (score 1):

The blob type can be different. On one side he can mean the [sql blob type](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Large_Object).
And most important is the MIME Type [like here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image)

If you are coding your API / Backend in Java it can look like this to stream an image to the client which requested the blob:

```
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response exportBlob( String blobName ) throws Exception
{
  Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob(yourBlobColumnIndex); //query the blob from the Database
  String type = "image/png"; // Set your needed MIME Type
  StreamingOutput data = createStreamingOutput( imageBlob ); // stream it as a binary
  return Response.ok( data, type ).build();
}
  /**
   * Creates an Outputstream of the Data from the given Blob.
   *
   * @param blob the blob that needs to be converted.
   * @return Outputstream of the Blob Data.
   * @throws WebApplicationException when the conversion failed.
   */
  private static StreamingOutput createStreamingOutput( final java.sql.Blob blob )
  {
    return output -> {
      try ( InputStream stream = blob.getBinaryStream() )
      {
            byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ( ( count = stream.read( buff ) ) != -1 )
            {
               if ( count > 0 )
              {
                output.write( buff, 0, count );
              }
           }
      }
      catch ( SQLException e )
      {
        throw new WebApplicationException( e.getMessage(), e );
      }
    };
  }
```

Converting it to Base64 is also an option. You have to adapt to what you can use in android to convert this binaryData back to an image again.

An example for android could be this:

```
//byteArray is what you recieved from the API in this example
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0 ,byteArray.length);
```

**EDIT:**

Since you stated that you have very few knowledge in this type of scenario let me add some resources.

1. How to save an actual image in a MySQL database [here](http://www.thecreativedev.com/how-to-store-a-file-in-database/) (This is not that different for other databases, besides syntax)
2. A little confusing example of BLOB handling at php [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=930)
3. A example for handling BLOBs in Java [here](https://www.orangeandbronze.com/orange-orchard/blog/2015/10/blob-handling-in-java-and-jdbc/)

There are often discussions about using BLOBs to save images. You could make life really really easy with just adding the base64 representation of an image in the database. This way you wouldn't need to handle the dataType BLOB. However I generally don't like that solution personally and prefer using BLOBs. ( I already added a article about blob so I won't do it again)

Also here are some links for getting into Backend development, but that's the part where your own effort comes into place. It's a lot to learn but don't be scared. Once you completed your base it will become simpler.

[Java Frameworks](https://dzone.com/articles/7-best-java-frameworks-for-2016)

[Interesting PHP Frameworks](http://mashable.com/2014/04/04/php-frameworks-build-applications/#C.NMBiagsaqJ)

[PHP Backend Tutorial](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-learn-Back-End-Development-from-scratch-I-am-not-from-a-computer-science-background-but-I-want-to-pursue-my-career-as-a-developer-Please-guide-me-What-should-I-do)

[Online course](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-backend--ud171)

Good luck on your journey!

Answer (score 1):

You try to encode all the images in base64 then insert into database then create api which fetch all the images from your database then you sync your android app with this api and store the images as sqlite in local database.
1.main profit is that now u can load your gallery imges offline also

Comment: Any links or tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

See, If you have your hosting account on hostinger, you'd get an option to create your own database without even writing a single line of mysql code.
For server side, you need to learn Php.
Also, it is never recommended to store images in the database.
Store them in your storage directory on your hosting site, and their links(URL) in the database. It would make fetching of Images faster.

For the android side, just use Picasso library which saves you time and space to load images from server.

You are all set to go. :)
Comment for queries.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to consider these two options for serving and storage of files:

1. [Overview of Blobstore API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/blobstore/?csw=1)
2. [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/)